# Regex find word inside string

Tags: php, regex

I've tried `^name&` but it does not work. How can I find a name inside `hello-my-name-is`

Comment: Check out http://regular-expressions.info/ to learn the basics. To solve your actual problem you might need to elaborate on the context and show the real data/input and what you want to get.

Answer (score 5):

`/.name./` The two points indicate, that there is at least one character on each side.

Comment: Old question, but shouldn't it be `.+` to match one or more characters?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is either `/name/` or `/\bname\b/`. `\b` is an indicator for word boundary. See this doc for more info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

The reason `^name$` doesn't give you any results when searching the string `"hello-my-name-is"` is because the character `^` anchors the search to the start of the string. Similarly `$` anchors the search to the end. For example:

- `^name` works only if the string started with `"name"` e.g. `"name is cool"`
- `name$` works only if the string ended with `"name"` e.g. `"where is name"`

For more info about anchors see this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: `&` is not the end of the string--you would need `$` for that.

Comment: None of this does the thing for me

Comment: @AndyMaccarther you might want to share the code you are using to search for the string so we can help you better.

Comment: @AndyMaccarther `.*` means find 0 or more characters, followed by `product_detail`, followed by `s*` = 0 or more `s`'s, and then followed by any character. I think you meant `.*product_details.*`

Answer (score 0):

`/name/` seems to work well here.

```
$str = "hello-my-name-is";
$str1 = preg_match("/name/", $str);
echo $str . " => " . $str1;
```

The output is -

```
hello-my-name-is => 1
```

Means it found the `name` subsctring, and it appeared 1 time.

Comment: Sorry its not for PHP its for something that uses REGEX how can i do it with regex?

Comment: @AndyMaccarther you've tagged your question with `php`. If it's not for php then you might want to remove the `php` tag.

Comment: @AndyMaccarthur, Regex Must be implemented with some language.. You cannot just write it anywhere.. my example shows the use using PHP, should work with any other language..